# Get view holder reference to previous item inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view containing Image and share button in different block.

I need to find reference to view holder of Image when share button in different block is clicked.

Below is onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

            case 49:
                MyViewHolder vh49 = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                final ImageView z = vh1.rashifalFullImage;
                // .. more lines followed
                break;
            case 50:
                MyViewHolder vh50 = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                // require reference to Imageview here
                // something like this final ImageView z = vh1.rashifalFullImage;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve such a thing? Sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'd bind the `ViewHolder` with all the necessary information. If the image is necessary on the share viewHolder, then it should be contained by it as well. Also, if these elements are really connect, why aren't they in the same view element?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through `RecyclerView` directly using [`findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)):

```
ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(49);
```